# Prove by contradiction. If the average of four different integers is 10 then one of them is greater than 10

Tags: logic

I was asked to prove by contradiction but I'm not get it so I decided to call for help

Comment: HInt:  If $m$ is the largest of the four, then the second largest can be at most $m-1$, the third largest can be at most $m-2$, and the least must be less than or equal to $m-3$.  Then you can use the definition of average to bound $m$.

Comment: Can you solve it systematically for me

Comment: In the hint, I gave an upper bound for each of the integers.  What do you get when you sum these upper bounds?  How does that sum related to the average?

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $a<b<c<d$

If $d\le10$

$$\dfrac{a+b+c+d}4<\dfrac{d+d+d+d}4\le10$$

Answer (score 0):

You may use this fact, "For any mathematical average, the sum of how much larger than the average the numbers above are must equal the sum of how much smaller than the average the numbers below are."

In mathematical words, if $L=\{l_j\}=\{x_i\in X\mid x_i<\bar{x}\}$ and $h=\{h_k\}=\{x_i\in X\mid x_i>\bar{x}\}$.

then, $\sum\limits _{j} (l_j-\bar{x}) = \sum\limits _k (h_k-\bar{x})$

Now suppose that no number is greater than $11$, then all the four numbers, $a<b<c<d \le 11$ (if you mean this $>11$, by greater than $11$)

And since they are different then if $d=11$ then you'll have $a<b<c \le 10$ and that how you get to your contradiction, because whatever numbers you take for $a,b,$ and $c$, the sum of how much smaller than $10$ the numbers below average are is strictly greater that the sum of how much  larger than $10$ the numbers above are.

Or, $\sum\limits _{j} (l_j-\bar{x}) > \sum\limits _k (h_k-\bar{x})$